# Why does HaShem refer to Himself in the third "person"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, joshua--book-of

In [Joshua 1:9](http://m.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15785/jewish/Chapter-1.htm#v=9), HaShem says to Joshua:

> Did I not command you, be strong and have courage, do not fear and do not be dismayed, for the Lord your God is with you wherever you go.

My wife asked a great question that I couldn't find an answer to in Miqra'ot Gedolot: why does HaShem refer to Himself in the third "person" ("for the Lord your God is with you [...]")?

Comment: this is answered elsewhere around here somewhere--it's the "Royal We"..and there's a lot of its usage in TaNaCh..